# Application Architecture for scalable hyperledger v1.4 with IOT data

Tags: amazon-ec2, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, iot, scalability

I am working on the Hyperledger Application that can store sensor data from *IoT*.
Using HLF v1.4 with **Raft**. Each IoT device will provide JSON data at fixed intervals which gets stored in Hyperledger. I have worked with HLF v1.3 which doesn't scale very well.

With v1.4, I am planning to start with 2 organization setup with 5 peers for each organization.

> But the limiting factor seems to be, as the number of blocks increase by adding new transactions and querying the network takes a longer time.

- **What are the steps that can be taken to scale the HLF with v1.4 or onwards.**
- **What type of Server specs should be used for good performance, like RAM, CPUs when selecting a server e.g EC2**

Answer (score 0):

You can change your block size. If you increase the size of your block, then the number of blocks will get reduced. For better query and Invoke functionality you can limit the data storing into Blockchain. Yes, Computation speed also matters in Blockchain, if you have good speed, tps may vary. Try with instance types like t3 medium or more than that like t3 large.